# String splits on KML conversion

Tags: kml, google-earth, google, string

I am opening this file with Google Earth and I am supposed to to do a bunch of string splits on the KML conversion since it saves the folder structure in the “PATH” field iirc. How can I do this?

Here is the file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dGKldQ_U8EMnAviqdni2JdZvfJuXSUDE/view?usp=sharing